# Rails Functional Test Case and Uploading Files to ActionDispatch::Http::UploadFile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, functional-testing

I'm am adding tests to a Rails app that remotely stores files. I'm using the default Rails functional tests. How can I add file uploads to them? I have:

```
test "create valid person" do
  post(:create, :person => { :avatar => fixture_file_upload('avatar.jpeg') })
end
```

This for some reason uploads a `Tempfile` and causes the `AWS/S3` gem to fail with:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `bytesize' for Tempfile
```

Is their any way that I can get the test to use an `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` and perform more like it does when testing with the web browser? Is `fixture_file_upload` the way to test uploading files to a controller? If so why doesn't it work like the browser?

As a note, I really don't want to switch testing frameworks. Thanks!

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I use the [s3 gem](https://github.com/qoobaa/s3) instead of the aws/s3 gem. The main reasons for this are no support for european buckets and development of aws/s3 seems to be stopped.

If you want to test file upload than using the *fixtures_file_upload* method is correct, it maps directly to *Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new* (you can use this if the test file isn't in the fixtures folder).

But I've also noticed that the behavior of the Rack::Test::Uploaded file objects isn't exactly the same as the ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile object (that's the class of uploaded files). The basic methods (original_filename, read, size, ...) all work but there are some differences when working with the file method. So limit your controller to these methods and all will be fine.

An other possible solution is by creating an ActionDispatch::Http::Uploaded file object and using that so:

```
upload = ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new({
  :filename => 'avatar.jpeg',
  :type => 'image/jpeg',
  :tempfile => File.new("#{Rails.root}/test/fixtures/avatar.jpeg")
})

post :create, :person => { :avatar => upload }
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay but this looks perfect! Really appreciate the answer!

Comment: +1, it's safer to use ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile because Rack::Test::Uploaded is not API compatible with Rails.

Comment: The attribute is `content_type` but you need tho pass the key :type into the initializer. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23899860/actiondispatchhttpuploadedfile-content-type-not-being-initialized-in-rspec-t)

Comment: `upload ` comes as `"#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f9b6642a208>"` string in params

Comment: I have the same problem as @sohair. This solution doesn't work, the file just comes to the controller as a string in the format he mentioned.

Comment: ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile did not work for me but Rack::Test::UploadedFile did. (https://www.trimagency.com/blogs/testing-a-multipart-form-upload-in-rails-rspec/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using mocks.
A quick google search reveals:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-mockrails/index.html

You should be able to create an object that will respond to the behaviors you want it to. Mostly used in a Unit test environment, so you can test your stuff in isolation, as integration tests are supposed to fully exercise the entire stack. However, I can see in this case it'd be useful to mock out the S3 service because it costs money.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I'm really looking to stick with using plain functional tests if possible! and I am very comfortable paying the micro fees to test the S3 service (as it is core).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the AWS/S3 gem, but it seems that you probably aren't using the :avatar param properly.  `bytesize` is defined on `String` in ruby1.9.  What happens if you call `read` on the uploaded file where you pass it into AWS/S3?

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. My code works fine when testing in the browser. I just need to add support for automated testing and would like the tests to use an `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` (that responds to `tempfile`, giving access to the file on disk) so I can integrate.