# ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.content_type not being initialized in Rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, multipartform-data

**Background**: I have a `Book` model with a `cover_file` attribute that gets set with an uploaded file via one of my Rails controllers. I'm using Rails v4.0.4.

**Goal**: I want to test that only files with certain content types get saved. I plan to create Rspec test examples with `ActionDispatch::Http:UploadedFile` objects set with different `content_type` attributes.

**Problem**: When I initialize a new `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` with a `content_type`, it doesn't seem to get set (see test & output below that confirms that it's nil). It seems that I can only set it with a setter AFTER the UploadedFile has been initialized. I don't see any mention of this behavior in the docs nor could I find a similar Q&A on SO, so I'd appreciate anyone's help in determine what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

**Code**:

```
describe Book do
  let(:book) {FactoryGirl.build(:book)}
  describe "Save" do
    context "with valid data" do
      before do
        cover_image = File.new(Rails.root + 'spec/fixtures/images/cover_valid.jpg')
        book.cover_file = ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new(tempfile: cover_image, filename: File.basename(cover_image), content_type: "image/jpeg")
        puts book.cover_file.content_type.nil?
        book.cover_file.content_type = "image/jpeg"
        puts book.cover_file.content_type
      end
      specify{expect(book.save).to be_true}
    end
  end
end
```

**Output**:

```
true
image/jpeg
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I looked at the Rails source file for the `UploadedFile` class and I found the issue.  For the @content_type attribute, for example, while the getter and setters are named as expected (`.content_type`), the `initialize` method looks for an attribute called `type` in the options hash.  The same thing happens for @original_filename; initialize looks for `filename` instead of `original_filename`. This seems to have been the case since the Rails 3 codebase.

So, if I change my code above to the following, everything works as expected:

`book.cover_file = ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new(tempfile: cover_image, filename: File.basename(cover_image), type: "image/jpeg")`

Relevant section of rails/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/upload.rb...

```
class UploadedFile
  # The basename of the file in the client.
  attr_accessor :original_filename

  # A string with the MIME type of the file.
  attr_accessor :content_type

  # A +Tempfile+ object with the actual uploaded file. Note that some of
  # its interface is available directly.
  attr_accessor :tempfile
  alias :to_io :tempfile

  # A string with the headers of the multipart request.
  attr_accessor :headers

  def initialize(hash) # :nodoc:
    @tempfile          = hash[:tempfile]
    raise(ArgumentError, ':tempfile is required') unless @tempfile

    @original_filename = encode_filename(hash[:filename])
    @content_type      = hash[:type]
    @headers           = hash[:head]
  end
```

Comment: Not surprising, but this appears to hold true for Rails 4.0 as well.

Comment: Same for Rails 5.x

Comment: And also for 6.x